# How to get HTML of dynamic page in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have two different views as below.

```
First: /Invoice/Print/?InvID=12345
Second: /Account/Index
```

Second `view` has a `button` to send Email. It will send the Invoice in email.
Invoice email format is generated on first view.

When we click on email `button` it goes to `controllers` then `model` and so on.

I want to access the `HTML` of first `view` in `controller` or `model` so that i can send it in email.

I don't have any clue that how we can do it in MVC.

Can anyone tell me what's the best way to achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

you need to regenerate `HTML` to send first view by email , so you can use `ViewEngines.Engines.FindView` to get your view and then render it using `View.Render` then send it by email.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the email template into a partial view (so you could reuse it), then
you can render the partial view into a string in the controller action so you could use it as email body:

This method taken from [Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string) will allow you to render partial view into a string:

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
  ViewData.Model = model;
  using (var sw = new StringWriter())
  {
    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                             viewName);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                 ViewData, TempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
    return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
  }
}
```

In the controller action that should send an email you can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult SendEmail(SomeModel model)
{
    //generate a model for an email:
    var emailModel = ....;

    //assuming that _EmailTemplate.cshtml is a partial view that contains the email template
    var emailBody = this.RenderRazorViewToString("_EmailTemplate",emailModel);

    //send the email here...
}
```